# algorithm2e - make the topmost and bottom horizontal lines thicker

Tags: rules, algorithm2e

[image: My example algorithm]

I'm pretty satisfied with the output above, yet would prefer having the topmost and the bottom horizontal lines bolder. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following length names seem to control the rule heights:

```latex
\setlength\algoheightrule{<height>}        % The upper and the lower rules
\setlength\algotitleheightrule{<height>} % The rule between a title and code
```

If you want to restore the default lengths, run the following

```latex
\setlength\algoheightrule{\algoheightruledefault} 
\setlength\algotitleheightrule{\algotitleheightruledefault}
```

The example:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\setlength\algoheightrule{2pt}        % Upper and lower rules
\setlength\algotitleheightrule{1.2pt} % Rule below the title

\begin{document}
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwData{Left}{left}\SetKwData{This}{this}\SetKwData{Up}{up}
    \SetKwFunction{Union}{Union}\SetKwFunction{FindCompress}{FindCompress}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}
    \Input{A bitmap $Im$ of size $w\times l$}
    \Output{A partition of the bitmap}
    \BlankLine
    \emph{special treatment of the first line}\;
    \For{$i\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $l$}{
    \emph{special treatment of the first element of line $i$}\;
    \For{$j\leftarrow 2$ \KwTo $w$}{\label{forins}
    \Left$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j-1]$}\;
    \Up$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i-1,]$}\;
    \This$\leftarrow$ \FindCompress{$Im[i,j]$}\;
    \If(\tcp*[h]{O(\Left,\This)==1}){\Left compatible with \This}{\label{lt}
    \lIf{\Left $<$ \This}{\Union{\Left,\This}}
    \lElse{\Union{\This,\Left}}
    }
    \If(\tcp*[f]{O(\Up,\This)==1}){\Up compatible with \This}{\label{ut}
    \lIf{\Up $<$ \This}{\Union{\Up,\This}}
    \tcp{\This is put under \Up to keep tree as flat as possible}\label{cmt}
    \lElse{\Union{\This,\Up}}\tcp*[h]{\This linked to \Up}\label{lelse}
    }
    }
    \lForEach{element $e$ of the line $i$}{\FindCompress{p}}
    }
    \caption{disjoint decomposition}\label{algo_disjdecomp}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}

\end{document}
```